# CSS: Ignore Indent on Center aligned text

Tags: css, indentation, text-align

Just started posting stories and essays online and I've found a couple sites that have very basic text editors that don't allow a lot of basic formatting unless you apply a CSS Workskin. After searching through the topics here I found some useful Code but ran into some problems. What I want to know is if there's a way to set Center Aligned text to ignore Indentation without setting it to a specific Class?

```css
#workskin p {
  text-indent: 45px;
}
```

I have the above set to indent the first line of every paragraph but it also indents everything that's centered which skews it off-center.  I hope there's some adjustment to the above code that forces it to ignore center aligned text.

```css
#workskin p.chapter {
  text-align:center;
  text-indent:0;
}
```

I learned how to set a Class as above to correct this but some of the postings I'll be making will require hundreds or thousands of center-aligned lines so I'm really hoping I can do it with some Code rather than having to manually set them to a Class. Thanks for any help you can give!

EDIT: To specify what I'm asking for, I want to force all center aligned text to have 0 indent so I don't have to manually insert:

```css
<p class="chapter">
```

Thousands of times.

Paragraph --- want Indent
Paragraph --- want Indent
Centered text/divider/chapter title/ect...  ---- do NOT want Indent
Paragraph --- want Indent
Centered text/divider/chapter title/ect...  ---- do NOT want Indent
pattern continues randomly

Comment: Check this fiddle with working example jsfiddle.net/j028dsae/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do something like:

```css
 #workskin p.chapter {
      display: block;
      text-align:center;
      text-indent:0!important;
     /* "!imporatnt" ensures that it overrides
     previous indent property set, if the value 0 
     and specification doesn't solve the problem */
    }
```

To indent just the first paragraph do something like below, none of the other paragraphs will not indent.

```
#workskin p:first-of-type { /* Targets just the first paragraph */
     text-indent: 45px;
}
```

Comment: Ah neat, I think I see how that works! But is there a way to apply this to documents with hundreds of paragraphs and lines of centered text since it only targets the first paragraph?

Answer (score 3):

The first style has a more specific selector than `p.chapter` so the text indent remains at 45px. You also need:

```css
#workskin p.chapter {   
    text-align:center;
    text-indent:0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, copy/paste mistake. Already had #workskin applied. Thanks though.